# Replicating svn:externals into a git repository (Referencing git from Subversion)

Tags: svn, git, svn-externals

We have a Subversion repository that is not going to move to git in the short to medium term, but I would like to use a DVCS for controlling and versioning 3rd party libraries.

Is there a way of using something like svn:externals to fetch/link a revision from git, driven by the Subversion checkout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this, since svn:externals are restricted to subversion repositories. You might use github for the git repositories, since github has [read+write](http://github.com/blog/644-subversion-write-support) support for svn.

Comment: It's not the answer I was looking for :-( , but it does seem to be the answer, so thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You may clone your SVN repository with [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html). It will create .gitsvnextmodules file that is analog to svn:externals for Git. SmartGit fully supports this format and displays submodules in the "Directories" view. To update .gitsvnextmodules using UI select a submodule among "Directory" and press Stage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure we have exactly the same problem, but I created a script to solve a similar issue: http://github.com/eneroth/git-externals

Comment: Thanks. I think we are going to have to bite the bullet and convert everything from SVN to GIT. It seems controlling GIT from SVN is just not going to happen!